# ASP.net:duplicate values from database in chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, duplicates

I work in a website using asp.net C# (inventory management project)

I have this database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[product] (
    [category_id] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [company_na]  VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [category]    VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [items]       VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [quantity]    VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([category_id] ASC)
);
```

And I use this code to show the category with % of quantity for each items in chart:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "select category ,quantity from product where company_na = '" + Label5.Text + "'";
            con.Open();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);
            string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
            int[] y = new int[dt.Rows.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                y[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1]);
            }
            Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);
            Chart1.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            foreach (DataPoint p in Chart1.Series[0].Points)
            {
                p.Label = "#PERCENT";
            }
```

but, It show duplicate category for each items . 
I want all categories without duplicate.

[image]

Comment: I think you need [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need [SELECT DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) in your query

```
cmd.CommandText = "select distinct category_id ,quantity from product where company_na = '" + Label5.Text + "'";
```

Comment: Hi, i try it . the same it shows all items . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Select distinct won't work Trisno, the problem is that Moon Light has more than one field he requires from the db and we don't really know the behavior of the other one. Anyway here's what I would do:

```
cmd.CommandText =
"SELECT  c2.field1 ,
        field2
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT
                field1
         FROM   dbo.TABLE AS C
        ) AS c1
        JOIN dbo.TABLE AS c2 ON c1.field1 = c2.field1'" + Label5.Text + "'";
```

Let me know if this helps ;)

Comment: hi, what you mean by c,c1, c2, field ?

Comment: c, c1, c2 are all references to the table they are declared as, so for example if you do a join from your products table you can represent it as p if you type something like "select p.category, p.quantity from products p". Have a look here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp for a better explanation of SQL joins. Those variables are just used mainly in SQL joins, I hope this makes sense.